# Bootstrap 4 does not work properly in Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) to install bootstrap 4.

I must have done a mistake somewhere, since in my app does not properly show bootstrap. For example, colors are not present or spaces are not available.

Can you spot my mistake?

Here is what I did:

First, I added these gems:

```
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
```

Then, I renamed application.css to application.scss and it now looks like this:

```
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
```

Finally, I changed application.js to this:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: Further Informations
Rails version: Rails 5.1.4
Ruby version: ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]

Example, where Bootstrap does not work properly:

Bootstraps provides code for cards. Cards have their own classes for background-color. [Here you can see,](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/) how it should look like (you have to scroll down to: Background variants )

And the picture below shows, how it looks in my app:

[image]

Comment: Any luck figuring this one out?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Sorry, I couldn't figured it out. I started to use a CDN like this one: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/